# Is it possible to join a different secret society?

Tags: the-secret-world

Can you change your faction without rerolling your character?  How?

If so, can you access faction-exclusive cutscenes for content you've missed? (The only real compelling reason to change factions short of PvP, I suppose).

Comment: Haven't found a way to change societies. Don't think it is possible either. I'm thinking your going to have to reroll your character. If i was a secret society, my only way out was death :p. My guess is so is theirs ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; you have to reroll to join another faction

> The secret societies are factions that players can join. United by a common goal to battle evil, they are nonetheless in conflict with each other in the pursuit of power. In the player-vs-player aspect of the game, they will compete with each other for resources, territory and world domination. Once you join a society, you are stuck with it for life.

Source: http://pc.ign.com/articles/102/1023335p1.html

> It will be impossible to change factions without creating a new character.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_World

Comment: This was my assumption, but I was really wondering if there were any sources on it.

Comment: Added some sources; but i found no offical statement on this topic.  I played the beta and now the game. I did not found any possibility to change the faction.

Comment: For some reason, there are specific faction points in your character sheet. I agree changing your faction afterwards looks not completely impossible. We have yet to find definite statements by funcom for or against.